# Required space for symfony cache - system crash

Tags: symfony, caching, server

Servus,

I just got a big server crash because the cache folder needed more and more disc space, at least around 400 GiB.

Is that normal? How can I set a limit? I just tested the system after removing the old folder - now the folder is growing each 5 minutes and needs round 5 MiB more space.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's the cache and not the logs using the disk space? If the logs are growing out of control it may indicate problems with your code.

Comment: Yes, I'm shure, it's the cache folder.